# What are the basics of using ROM-based controller in lieu of discrete logic

Tags: computer-architecture

In Computer Architecture and Organization, how can one use ROM-based controllers instead of discrete logic? My teacher explained a bit, but I can't find any details anywhere online (well, I looked on Bing).

Comment: Somewhat related: [Advantages and disadvantages of microcoded vs hardcoded architectures](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/28388/4577)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any logical transformation of N input bits to M output bits can be accomplished by a look-up table with 2<sup>N</sup> entries (indexed by the input bits) of M bits each. This is effectively joining together M truth tables each using the same N inputs.

Using a look-up table can be simpler (less error-prone) and friendlier to change than using many individual logical operations to generate the same result. In addition, at times the cost of ROM has been much smaller than the cost of arbitrary logic.

In some cases a compromise design is superior. Discrete logic might be used to compress the input to reduce the size of the table, independent portions of the input might each use a smaller table (requiring a little extra logic to parse the input before the look-up), or simple transformations (such as duplicating particular bits or conditionally inverting particular bits) might be applied to the look-up table result allowing a reduction in the number of bits per ROM entry or the number of ROM entries.

(A similar set of tradeoffs exists for a "hardware" implementation of complex instructions versus the use of microcode.)

Comment: I think I understand (especially the first paragraph), but I will need to find an example illustrating this comparison to really see clear. Thank you, Mr. Clayton.

Answer (score 1):

The question is "how" to use a ROM-based controller in place of discrete logic.

Your program in the controller could look like this:

```
// some setup stuff
 ...
for(;;)  // do forever 
{
// read inputs
 ...
// do some calculations
 ...
// write to outputs
 ...
}
```

The above is exactly how Programmable Logic Controllers (PLCs) replace discrete relay logic.

The loop execution time will determine how fast the outputs respond to the inputs, and that depends, in part, on the complexity of the program. In most cases, this is going to be microseconds or even milliseconds rather than nanoseconds.

Mr. Clayton's answer is oriented toward using a ROM to replace discrete logic, which is a bit different. If you came up with sequential logic, say to evaluate a 16-bit sin(x), it would be fairly complex and take perhaps 1,000 clock cycles. If you were to simply program a 65536 x 16bit ROM with pre-calculated values of sin(x), then you need only present the input value at the address lines and read the output from the data lines, probably some tens of nanoseconds later.

Even with huge memories, the approach runs out of steam quickly with larger bit widths and more than one input variable.